# What would be the best way to make Spark work over proprietery distributed DB? (RDD or FileInputFormat)

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

We have some kind of distributed Data store. We know all internals and can access the data directly on disk.

I'm investigating the option to deploy Apache Spark directly over it.

What would be the best/recommended way to do it?

- Writing **Custom RDD** (derive from RDD)
- Or, through **extending FileInputFormat**?

(Is one easier than the other?  Better performance? etc.)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spark 1.2 will include a new external data sources API for Spark SQL.  This will make it easy to write new input connectors for loading (semi-)structured data and querying it from SQL, and will have hooks to enable data-source-specific query optimizations, such as partition pruning or predicate pushdown.  Even if you're not using Spark SQL to query your data (e.g. you want to use the regular RDD API), this is probably the easiest way to load it, since you can perform regular Spark transformations on SchemaRDDs.

Here are a few resources for learning more about this API:

- The second half of [*The Spark SQL Optimizer and External Data Sources API* Meetup talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GQSNJAzxOr8) discusses the new API and shows an example of writing a connector to read from Avro files.
- [Pull request to add these APIs](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/2475)
- [SPARK-3247](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3247) JIRA for tracking progress on this feature.

Answer (score 3):

I would go with CustomRDD. As reference you can take a look at datastax-cassandra-driver, they have very good example of writing custom RDD for distributed database

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/rdd/CassandraRDD.scala

However as I understand they are not bothering with loading data from disk, they use partition information from Cassandra to partition RDD itself. However it should be relatively straightforward to support what you need.

Comment: thanks, don't have much reputation yet to vote up :-)

Comment: Went over the new API. One still need to implement the RDD.